# How to confirm whether the delivered message is viewed or not in twilio?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-functions

In my application, there is two factor authentication. For that we are using Twilio services. Is there any way to confirm whether the message sent was read or not (i.e. The user has opened the message). Please suggest a method.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

from my knowledge there is no read status in SMS, not particular to twilio, but generally sms does not provide a read feedback, rather there is Delivered, Undelivered, Failed Statuses

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134347-What-do-the-SMS-statuses-mean-

[Track Delivery of SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-csharp)